# Как с помощью GWT фреймворка, изменить цвет при нажатии на кнопку? Писать только на java нужно

Tags: java, gwt

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Client implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        Button button = new Button("Click me");
        RootPanel.get().add(button);
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            final public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: можешь показать на примере моём?

Comment: Вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634050 можно закрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти нужный [`Element`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html) и потом `.getStyle().setBackgroundColor(...)`, например. Или через `toggleClassName(...)` менять класс, который объявлен в CSS.

```
Element el = Document.get().getElementById("my-div");
el.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");
// или
el.toggleClassName("my-red-class"); // в CSS: .my-red-class { background-color: #ff0000 }
```